# Can't re import python tensorflow module

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.9.0 under python 3.6. After importing tensorflow, I can't use importlib to reload it - example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import importlib

importlib.reload(tf)
```

This crashes eventually with :

```
~/anaconda/envs/tf1pt9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
    592 # resolution to succeed.
    593 # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
--> 594 del python
    595 del core
    596 # pylint: enable=undefined-variable

NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

Isn't that weird? I guess I don't need to reload it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reloading tensorflow is not supported.  From an issue on Github:

> Closing since we don't have plans to support reload anytime soon.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15741